# finding the path of file in a Java program

Tags: java

In the following Java program (only showing a part of the whole program)
I have the follwing code:

```
private final File test_data_file;
private final int algorithm_selection;

private double average_pos_err, average_exe_time;

// The scan list to use for offline
private ArrayList<LogRecord> OfflineScanList;

public OfflineMode(RadioMap RM, File test_data_file, int algorithm_selection, Handler handler) {
    this.RM = RM;
    this.test_data_file = test_data_file;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.algorithm_selection = algorithm_selection;
    this.OfflineScanList = new ArrayList<LogRecord>();
}

public void run() {

    if (!test_data_file.isFile() || !test_data_file.exists() || !test_data_file.canRead()) {
        errMsg = test_data_file + " does not exist or is not readable";
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);
        return;
    }
```

I want to track down, the path of the variable "test_data_file" of type File,  but the code does not seems to show me any directions.
do you know where I can find it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not call [`getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath()) on the File?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File#getAbsolutePath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) or [File#getCanonicalPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) which will resolve the path fully (removing relative components)

Comment: I just want to see path for debugging porpuses (I can't run the code) is there a way to see the path from the debugging console? thanks!

Comment: That depends, what IDE are using?

Comment: I am using java's Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

using by java 7 you can get file type

```
String fileType = Files.probeContentType(test_data_file.getPath());
```

for more detail you can refers 
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29

Comment: can execute that on the debugger?